# Update variable and use it immediately React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, state, setstate

I am trying to update a variable after an api call but I will use a click event for this question.

As you can see, the variable that i print uses the old state on the first click as it doesn't register the change yet. On the following calls the variable gets printed with the new text.

Is there a way to use the updated variable immediately within the changeText function?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-36jqi3

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('inital text');

  const changeText = () => {
    setText('new text');
    console.log(text);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeText}>Update variable</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you need it update immediately and don't want the app to re-render, I think useRef would probably work, but without knowing what you want it do to it's hard to say

Comment: useRef was actually what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

No.

The `changeText` function that is currently running will have closed over the value of `text` from the value assigned during the render that created the `changeText` function.

The next render of the component will generate a new `changeText` function and assign it to `onClick`.

If you want to use the value you've just passed to `setState` then keep a copy of that value somewhere else.

```
const changeText = () => {
  const newValue = 'new text';
  setText(newValue);
  console.log(newValue);
};
```

Alternatively, do the work that needs the new value in an effect hook that triggers when that value changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(text);
}, [text]);

const changeText = () => {
  setText('new text');
};
```

That will trigger the hook on the *initial* render too though so you might want to add an extra test to make sure it isn't the initial value before logging it.

Answer (score -1):

Can get by way.

```js
export default function App() {
  

  const [text, setText] = useState('inital text');


  const changeText = () => {
    /* Calling updater to get the latest value. */
    setText('new text');
    setText((state) => {
       console.log("immediately updated text -->", state); 
       return state;
    });
  };



  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeText}>Update variable</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```